# javascript code doesn't display the answer of future value after I click the calculate button

Tags: javascript

I'm working on the fv calculator. However, I don't know why my JavaScript code doesn't display the answer of future value after I click the calculate button.

How could I solve this problem?

I will be appreciated if someone could offer me help, thanks.

Below is my HTML and JavaScript code.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>401K Future Value Calculator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mpg.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>401K Future Value Calculator</h2>

    <form id="calculationForm" >
      <label for="periodicPayment">Yearly Investment($): </label>
      <select id="yearlyInvest" name="Investment”">
        <option value="1000: ">1000</option>
        <option value="2000: ">2000</option>
        <option value="3000: ">3000</option>
        <option value="4000: ">4000</option>
        <option value="5000: ">5000</option>
        <option value="6000: ">6000</option>
        <option value="7000: ">7000</option>
        <option value="8000: ">8000</option>
        <option value="9000: ">9000</option>
        <option value="10000: ">10000</option>
      </select><br><br>

      <label for="annunalInterest">Annual Interest Rate(%) </label>
      <input type="text" id="annunalInterestRate"><br><br>

      <label for="years">Number of Years(#) </label>
      <input type="text" id="numOfYears"><br><br>

      <label for="future">Future Value($) </label>
      <p id="futureValue">       
      </p>

      <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate">
      <input type="button" onclick="clearButton()" id="clear" value="Clear">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
function processForm() {

  var r, n, p;

  r = parseFloat(document.getElementById("annunalInterestRate").value);
  n = parseInt(document.getElementById("numOfYears").value);
  p = document.getElementById("yearlyInvest").value;

  if (isNaN(r)) {
    alert("Pleas enter a valid number.");
  } else if (isNaN(n)) {
    alert("Pleas enter a valid number.");
  } else {
    var fv = P * ((Math.pow((1 + r), n) - 1) / r);
  }
  document.getElementById("calculate").value;
  document.getElementById("futureValue").innerHTML = fv.toFixed(2);
};

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = processForm;
};

function clearButton() {
  document.getElementById("calculationForm").reset();
}
```

Comment: You use the an uppercase `P` when calculating `fv`, but a lowercase `p` for the declared variable

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response, I change the p to lowercase. However, the innerHTML doesn't display the result as well. Any things I need correct in my code? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've written your `<option>` nodes in the `<select>` contain an unnecessary `:` in the `value=` param. This is causing `p` to compute as `NaN`. Instead, rewrite as:

```
<select id="yearlyInvest" name="Investment”">
        <option value="1000">1000</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
        ...
</select>
```